# Join to collections in mongodb

Tags: json, mongodb

I am trying to get the data from two collections in the same json object response.
I am trying to join both collection with $lookup but it does not work:

```
db.getCollection('profiles').aggregate( [
 {
    { 
     $match: {_id: ObjectId(userId) } 
     },

     $lookup: {
                  from: "users",
                  localField: "user",
                  foreingField: "_id",
                  as: "user_data"  

                }
 }
])
```

in the profile model user is declared like this:

```
 user: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        required: [ true, 'A reference to a user must exist']
    },
```

This is the debbug query i can see in my console :

```
Mongoose: users.aggregate([ { '$match': { _id: 5eec20720ff19056d079e953 } }, { '$lookup': { from: 'profile', localField: '_id', foreignField: 'user', as: 'profile_data' } }], {})
```

Comment: The title in English: "Create attribute on JSON object dynamically" post this in SO Spanish.

Comment: db.user.aggregate([{ $unionWith: "Collection1"  },{ $unionWith: "Collection2" }, ....])

Comment: Sorry my fault, I was thinking in spanish, how can I edit it? Thanks

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear is the `name` and `surname` cane from `user`?

Comment: You said `profile` model but you write `user`. `here:  user: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        required: [ true, 'A reference to a user must exist']
    }`. If you can place the shape of your models (even partially) I'll help much.

Answer (score 0):

**Skip until...**
Your question is a bit unclear. Is the name and surname came from the user? If so, you can do like below:

```
const response = {
    code: 200,
    profile: {
        name: user.name,
        surname: user.surname,
        email: profile.email
    }
}
```

You can then stringify it:

```
JSON.stringify(response);
```

Or send it like (If you are using express):

```
response.send(response);
```

**Until here...**

---

**EDIT:** Now that I understand the problem, this will be the answer:

Assume that your models are like below ana you stored the data like this:

```
const User = mongoose.model(
    'User',
    new mongoose.Schema({
        email: {
            type: String,
        },
    })
);
const Profile = mongoose.model(
    'Profile',
    new mongoose.Schema({
        name: {
            type: String,
        },
        rate: {
            type: Number,
        },
        user: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: User,
        },
    })
);

async function createAndSaveThem() {
    let user = new User({
        email: 'blah@blah.blah',
    });
    await user.save();
    let profile = new Profile({
        name: 'You',
        rate: 4,
        user: user._id,
    });
    await profile.save();
}

try {
    createAndSaveThem();
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
}
```

You can your data the way you want, like this (without aggregate):

```
async function getThem() {
    const profile = await Profile.findOne({ name: 'You'}).populate('user');

    const response = {
        code: 200,
        date: {
            name: profile.name,
            rate: profile.rate,
            email: profile.user.email
        }
    }    
    console.log('1', response); 
}

try {
    getThem();
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
}
```

Or this(using aggregate):

```
async function getThemWithAggregate() {
    let profile = await Profile.aggregate([
        { $match: { name: 'You' } },
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: 'users',
                localField: 'user',
                foreignField: '_id',
                as: 'user',
            },
        },
        { $unwind: '$user' },
        { $project: { name: 1, rate: 1, email: '$user.email', _id: 0 } },
    ]);
    const response = {
        code: 200,
        date: profile[0]
    }    
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response,0,2)); 
}

try {
    getThemWithAggregate();
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
}
```

Both will Output:

```
{
  "code": 200,
  "date": {
    "name": "You",
    "rate": 4,
    "email": "blah@blah.blah"
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes you are right, it was not very clear, that's why I edited my question again. I just want to join to collections in the same json response, as I explained above. Thanks

Comment: Ok, I could find a solution thanks to Armamedia, but to be honest I would like to undertand how can I join the to collections.

Comment: I think a population will the way to go. But I need the shape of your models.

Comment: Sorry I have to correct myself again, I solved it with population as you said, just creating a new object and added it to the response (instead of the original one). Many thanks.

Comment: Your welcome. I edited the answer now that I understand the problem. Just don't forget to mark my answer as correct. Also, tell me if you need me to add anything to it or edit it.

Comment: Thank you, I am new here and I am not sure how to mark the answer as correct. Thanks, finally as I said i solved with populate, I could not make it works with aggregation unfortunately.

Comment: You're welcome! There is a **Checkmark** (tickmark) on the **Left** **Top** of the answer. Under the upward and downward arrows ( like and dislike arrow or upvote and downvote arrow... ), **between arrows and clap sign**.  It enough visible. when you hit it, It'll become green. This way the answer marks as the correct answer (or chosen answer). This was the guy who answered get some reputation. The answerer help Questioner with the answer and the questioner helps the answerer too. It's **a Win-Win strategy**.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, finally I find a solution thanks to Armamedia answer, but to be honest I would like to understand how can I join this two collections in the same json object. At the moment I solved it like this, with 2 queries, one to the profile collection, and the second one to the user collection.

```
   const profile = await getUserProfile( userId, select );
   const user   = await User.find({"_id": userId}).select('email _id');

   return res.json({
        code: 200,
        data: {
            "name": profile[0].name,
            "email": user[0].email,
            "rate": profile[0].rate,    
        }

    })
```